# Как открыть сайт как анонимайзер?

Tags: php, jquery, iframe

Есть сервисы по подбору авиабилетов имеющие партнёрские программы, например http://www.skyscanner.ru/ , но проблема в том что многие из них (в том числе и http://www.skyscanner.ru/) не позволяют открывать себя во фрейме.

Проверил сайт через анонимайзер http://cameleo.ru/ (честно говоря подумал что тут тоже iframe задействован), http://www.skyscanner.ru/ открылся, но в коде нет iframe, сайт подрузился в DOM http://cameleo.ru/ при этом работают все скрипты и пр.

Собственно вопрос, как они это делают? http://www.skyscanner.ru/ загрузился в тело другого сайта, никаких запретов, все скрипты работают. Как?

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы открыть на своем сайте сервис, имеющий партнерскую программу, не нужно химичить с ифреймами и анонимайзерами. Надо заключить договор, получить ключ для API, [подключить на своем сайте API](http://business.skyscanner.net/portal/en-GB/Documentation/WhiteLabelv2HowToUse), и выдавать в браузер код, полученный через API.

Comment: тут дело не в крысятничестве, мы сами предоставляем поиск по авиабилетам и хотим для сравнения открывать сайты конкурентов с такими же условиями поиска, чтобы клиент мог выбрать у кого дешевле. Но часть конкурентов во фрейме не открывается, потому и ищу другой способ показать их предложения у нас на сайте ))

Answer (score 0):

Я так понимаю, вопрос не про партнёрки, а про принцип действия анонимайзеров, так всё очень просто — сервер просто сам скачивает страницу, слегка редактирует её под себя и отдаёт её пользователю. Простейший (но кривой) анонимайзер нетрудно написать самостоятельно за часок. http://pastebin.com/wnHFtxEK

[image: img]

(cameleo.ru заводит отдельный домен под сайт, и в таком случае городить такие замены ссылок, как в моём примере, не обязательно)

Answer (score 0):

Они выводят сайт не на клиентской стороне(iframe или инными способами), а на стороне сервера.
Их сервер запрашивает сайт церез аннонимный проксы сервер и выдает содержимое вам обработав перед этим(заменив ссылки, подправив js код и т.д.)